# Литература по разработке под Windows

Tags: windows, книги

Подскажите какую-нибудь литературу для разработчика под Windows по устройству Windows.

Хотелось бы какой-нибудь подробный справочник по абсолютно всем функциям Win32 API. В интернете находил такого рода книги, но они либо описывают усеченный перечень самых необходимых функций Win32 API, либо описывают функции версий Windows не выше Windows XP.

То есть хотелось бы справочник с абсолютно всеми функциями Win32 API, и чтобы были функции Win7.

А есть ли какой-нибудь полностью переведённый на русский язык вариант справки MSDN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Более подробного и технически грамотного справочника, чем "[Внутреннее устройство Microsoft Windows: Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, Windows 2000. Мастер-класс](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2427699/)" [Марка Руссиновича](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mark_russinovich/) - основателя [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals) и автора утилит, выпускаемых от ее имени, на русском языке вы точно не найдете - берите эту книгу, уверяю, для системного программиста она актуальна и сейчас, не сомневайтесь. Книгу можно легко найти на трекерах.

В windows немало недокументированных api, так что любое описание будет неполным. И в MSDN также описаны далеко не все. Думаю, не надо объяснять почему так.

Comment: Благодарю. А есть ли ещё что-н. подробно по DWM API почитать по-русски ?

Comment: Вот про dwm не подскажу, дел с ним не имел.